# Using ransackable_attributes with Active Admin errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin, ransack

We have a Rails 6.1 app with `activeadmin` 2.9.0 and `ransack` 2.4.2 and when we visit
`/admin/users` we get the following error:

**ArgumentError in Admin::Users#index**

**Polymorphic associations do not support computing the class.**

The error goes away if we remove the following section:

```rb
  #app/models/user.rb
  def self.ransackable_attributes(auth_object = nil)
    super & %w(first_name last_name slug)
  end
```

We need this section to prevent users being able to guess someone else's password or email.

Is there a better way to whitelist which `User` columns are searchable or to prevent this error?

The repo is open source if you want to try to reproduce:
https://github.com/fablabbcn/makeworks

Comment: does `slug` a `polymorphic association` ?

Comment: `slug` is a column from the `friendly_id` gem